# Does GlassFish servlet container use that catalina?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, glassfish

I am running the same servlet application in both Apache Tomcat and GlassFish servers.
I wanted to see the ServletConfig and ServletContext implementation class names.
Surprisingly, I found that GlassFish is also using from Apache Tomcat's catalina classes. Is my observation correct? If yes, why isn't GlassFish using its own servlet implementation classes?

[image: Running a Servlet in Apache Tomcat server]

[[image: Running a Servlet in GlassFish Server2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this FAQ entry](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/wiki-archive/FaqGlassFishTomcat.html) the Glassfish web container is a fork of Tomcat 5.5. Therefore it uses the same package names, although Tomcat's code has evolved a lot since the fork.

Comment: Also, ServletContext interface has a log() method; documentation mentions that the name and type of the servlet log file is specific to the implementation. I tried a little googling but couldn't get the name of the log file. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Both log through `java.util.logging`, so they are configured using `logging.properties`. By default Tomcat logs to `localhost.<date>.log`, GlassFish to `server.log`. Anyway I would advise against logging through `ServletContext#log`: you should use a logging framework like Log4j or Logback instead.